# How to Combine an IF and For/Foreach for checking multiple items?

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to write a Function using an If statement that checks an array of Defenition for a word and if one of them is right, it operates a "Success" Void, else it "Fails".
Question is, how to I properly combine the If and For statesments?
(It also needs to check it's property is not Null...)

It all works fine with stupid "Linear" coding:

```
private void Check()
{
    if ((textBox2.Text == Heb[Line].Def[0] || textBox2.Text == Heb[Line].Def[1] || textBox2.Text == Heb[Line].Def[2] || textBox2.Text == Heb[Line].Def[3] || textBox2.Text == Heb[Line].Def[4])&& textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        Success();
    }
    else
    {
        Fail();
    }
}
```

But i am sure there is a better and finer way to phrase it.

I want to use the "foreach" method to check def[].

I guess it should look something like:

```
if (foreach(int i in Heb[line].Def{(if Heb[Line].Def[i]==textBox2.Text})) something something...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) && Heb[Line].Def.Contains(textBox2.Text))
{ 
    Success(); 
}
else
{
    Fail();
}
```